# "This made tears creep to/from her eyes"

Tags: prepositions

I have been reading a novel for the past few days. I read something that did not sound good to me. I read this sentence in the novel:

> This made tears creep **to** her eyes.

But I did not understand why the writer used the preposition *to* here. As per my opinion the writer could have used the preposition *from* instead of *to*:

> This made tears creep **from** her eyes.

Does this sentence make sense using *from*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The writer probably used the form

> This made tears creep **to** her eyes

to stress that the heroine is not shedding tears yet, but feels [on the verge](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_the_verge) of tears: she feels that she could start shedding tears at any moment.

Sometimes we use the verb *to creep* to mark that someone or something is approaching stealthily, in an invisible fashion. In our example, other persons might fail to notice the fact that the woman is on the verge of tears, and only she herself feels tears *creeping* to her eyes, probably against her will or intent.

Judging by Google, the form `creep from her eyes` is extremely rare, with only 13 occurrences.